# Understanding Big(O) in loops

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

I am trying to get the correct Big-O of the following code snippet:

```
s = 0
for x in seq:
  for y in seq:
    s += x*y
  for z in seq:
    for w in seq:
      s += x-w
```

According to the book I got this example from (Python Algorithms), they explain it like this:

> The z-loop is run for a linear number of iterations, and
> it contains a linear loop, so the total complexity there is quadratic, or Θ(n<sup>2</sup>). The y-loop is clearly Θ(n).
> This means that the code block inside the x-loop is Θ(n + n<sup>2</sup>). This entire block is executed for each
> round of the x-loop, which is run n times. We use our multiplication rule and get Θ(n(n + n<sup>2</sup>)) = Θ(n<sup>2</sup> + n<sup>3</sup>)
> = Θ(n<sup>3</sup>), that is, cubic.

What I don't understand is: how could **O(n(n+n<sup>2</sup>))** become **O(n<sup>3</sup>)**. Is the math correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The math being done here is as follows.  When you say O(n(n + n<sup>2</sup>)), that's equivalent to saying O(n<sup>2</sup> + n<sup>3</sup>) by simply distributing the n throughout the product.

The reason that O(n<sup>2</sup> + n<sup>3</sup>) = O(n<sup>3</sup>) follows from the formal definition of big-O notation, which is as follows:

> A function f(n) = O(g(n)) iff there exists constants n<sub>0</sub> and c such that for any n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>, |f(n)| ≤ c|g(n)|.

Informally, this says that as n gets arbitrary large, f(n) is bounded from above by a constant multiple of g(n).

To formally prove that n<sup>2</sup> + n<sup>3</sup> is O(n<sup>3</sup>), consider any n ≥ 1.  Then we have that

> n<sup>2</sup> + n<sup>3</sup> ≤ n<sup>3</sup> + n<sup>3</sup> = 2n<sup>3</sup>

So we have that n<sup>2</sup> + n<sup>3</sup> = O(n<sup>3</sup>), with n<sub>0</sub> = 1 and c = 2.  Consequently, we have that

> O(n(n + n<sup>2</sup>)) = O(n<sup>2</sup> + n<sup>3</sup>) = O(n<sup>3</sup>).

To be truly formal about this, we would need to show that if f(n) = O(g(n)) and g(n) = O(h(n)), then f(n) = O(h(n)).  Let's walk through a proof of this.  If f(n) = O(g(n)), there are constants n<sub>0</sub> and c such that for n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>, |f(n)| ≤ c|g(n)|.  Similarly, since g(n) = O(h(n)), there are constants n'<sub>0</sub>, c' such that for n ≥ n'<sub>0</sub>, g(n) ≤ c'|h(n)|.  So this means that for any n ≥ max(c, c'), we have that

> |f(n)| ≤ c|g(n)| ≤ c|c'h(n)| = c x c' |h(n)|

And so f(n) = O(h(n)).

To be a bit more precise - in the case of the algorithm described here, the authors are saying that the runtime is Θ(n<sup>3</sup>), which is a stronger result than saying that the runtime is O(n<sup>3</sup>).  Θ notation indicates a tight asymptotic bound, meaning that the runtime grows at the same rate as n<sup>3</sup>, not just that it is bounded from above by some multiple of n<sup>3</sup>.  To prove this, you would also need to show that n<sup>3</sup> is O(n<sup>2</sup> + n<sup>3</sup>).  I'll leave this as an exercise to the reader. :-)

More generally, if you have *any* polynomial of order k, that polynomial is O(n<sup>k</sup>) using a similar argument.  To see this, let P(n) = ∑<sub>i=0</sub><sup>k</sup>(a<sub>i</sub>n<sup>i</sup>).  Then, for any n ≥ 1, we have that

∑<sub>i=0</sub><sup>k</sup>(a<sub>i</sub>n<sup>i</sup>) ≤ ∑<sub>i=0</sub><sup>k</sup>(a<sub>i</sub>n<sup>k</sup>) = (∑<sub>i=0</sub><sup>k</sup>(a<sub>i</sub>))n<sup>k</sup>

so P(n) = O(n<sup>k</sup>).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, your answer is truly mathematical.  I have to go back and review a lot from my days in comp sci school in order to understand this.  I'll get it eventually!

Comment: In your last equation, why do you assume that i is always less than k??  I mean, what if i=1000 and k=100

Comment: @IgorG.- The variable i is a counter in the summation, so by definition it ranges from 0 to k.  The idea is that a_i n^i represents one term in the polynomial.  For example, in 2x^3 + x^2 - 4x - 8, the sequence a_i is 2, 1, -4, -8.

Answer (score 7):

n(n+n<sup>2</sup>) == n<sup>2</sup> + n<sup>3</sup>

Big-O notation only cares about the dominant term as n goes to infinity, so the whole algorithm is thought of as Θ(n<sup>3</sup>).

Comment: We should be clear - that this refers to **Big Theta notation**.

Comment: Good point, @IgorGanapolsky. Note Θ(n^3) and not O(n^3). Big Oh only describes the upper bound, while Big Theta also describes the lower bound.

Answer (score 7):

```
O(n(n+n^2)) = O(n^2 + n^3)
```

Since the `n^3` term dominates the `n^2` term, the `n^2` term is negligible and thus it is `O(n^3)`.

Comment: Thanks.  That is what I am trying to understand: what does it mean "dominates"?  I am fuzzy with the terms like "function grows faster than..."

Comment: Informally speaking, it means that the `n^3` term grows much larger than the `n^2` term. So for example if `n=1000`, `n^3` is 3 orders of magnitude larger than `n^2`. For a more formal and rigorous treatment of Big-O, you will have to resort back to the precise definition.

Comment: Another way to explain this is that f(n) grows bigger than g(n) if its output(result) is bigger.

Comment: So would Big-o of n^3/1000 - 100*n^2 - 100*n + 3 be n^3?

Answer (score 1):

The y loop can be discounted because of the z loop (O(n) + O(n^2) -> O(n^2))
Forget the arithmetic.
Then you're left with three nested loops that all iterate over the full length of 'seq', so it's O(n^3)

Comment: I thought the z loop is O(n^2) because it contains a nested loop which iterates over the same collection.  So wouldn't the z loop be O(n*n) rather than O(n) + O(N)?