# Trying to understand the differences between Θ(n2) and Θ(n) in regards to run-time

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, time, big-o

I am trying to learn about the differences between Θ(n2) and Θ(n).  I started with [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), my textbook, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522463/help-calculating-big-o), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115129/big-o-notation-for-two-simple-recursive-functions) and then tried to create the following simple example for my beginner understanding.  When comparing the run-times of this snippet of code in Python 2.7, where I would comment out `option #1` when timing `option #2`, and comment out `option #2` when timing `option #1`:

```
import timeit

start = timeit.default_timer()

a = []
a.extend(range(1, 10))

b = []
b.extend(range(1, 10))

c = []
c.extend(range(1, 100))

# option 1
for x in a:
    for y in b:
        print("-")
# option 2
# for x in c:
#   print ("-")

stop = timeit.default_timer()

print stop - start
```

each line is an output per run, and I have prepended a `#1 -` or `#2 -` for clarity:

```
#1 - 0.000207901000977
#1 - 0.000203132629395
#1 - 0.000202178955078
#1 - 0.000203847885132
#1 - 0.000203847885132

#2 - 0.000240087509155
#2 - 0.000240087509155
#2 - 0.0142140388489
#2 - 0.000237941741943
#2 - 0.000246047973633
```

Both options print `-` 100 times.  I had assumed Θ(n2) is slower than Θ(n), even with a trivial case, yet, `option #1`, with Θ(n2), outperformed `option #2` with Θ(n).

Comment: The two are **not comparable**. **Both** loops execute 100 times. It is not n squared versus n, because n is 10 in one case, 100 in the other. Effectively, both are O(n) algorithms, you execute `print()` exactly n times in both cases.

Comment: Your timings are otherwise too close, and hampered by I/O (writing to the terminal) to say anything meaningful about the times.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you. I am learning about Big-O just now, and thank you for correcting my misunderstanding of my textbook which associated nesting with Θ(n2) without your qualification of **comparability**.

Comment: If an algorithm takes N **inputs** but then uses nested loops over the input, *then* you have a quadratic problem. You didn't use N inputs, you used sqrt(N), and then used a nested loop over that.

Comment: Even though it's not really applicable here, the answer to the question in your title is extremely simple: A O(n^x) algorithm (with x > 1) can easily outperform an O(n) algorithm as long as (1) n is sufficiently small and (2) the O(n) algorithm has a higher cost for each step. For example, imagine each step in the O(n) algorithm takes 1h, and each step in an equivalent O(n^3) algorithm takes 1ms - the O(n^3) algo will be faster for n smaller than ~1500. The O notation just describes the asymptotic behaviour of the algorithm, not the actual runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not comparing an O(N<sup>2</sup>) algorithm with an O(N) algorithm.

**Both** algorithms are, essentially O(N); you are executing `print` N times. But in the first option, you take the *square root* of N in an outer loop and the same square root in the inner loop, creating a O(sqrt(N) * sqrt(N)) == O(N) algorithm.

You can never compare the timings of two algorithms by just varying the value of N otherwise. *Normally* you take a look at the *inputs* to an algorithm. Sorting for example, looks at the number of elements to sort, and the best sorting algorithms will take NlogN steps to sort such a list. You were trying to compare the *output* instead; `print()` being executed N times in total.

Putting it differently, if option one takes *N* as the input, runs in O(N<sup>2</sup>) time (prints N<sup>2</sup> times), then option two takes *M* input, runs in O(M) time, but **M = N * N**. As a result, the second option runs in O(N<sup>2</sup>) time *as well*, but you merely produced the N<sup>2</sup> repetitions differently.

The timing differences are otherwise too close to call and can be down to I/O waits (you are writing to a terminal).

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that you actually have three inputs to consider rather than one. Option A is O(A * B), while option B is O(C), where A is the length of a, B is the size of b and C is the size of c. Meaning that you can't really directly compare the two algorithms.

Your choice of input values mean that it just so happens that O(a) = O(b) and O(c) = O(a * b) resulting in the same performance and complexity in this particular case.

You could convert this into a single input problem where option A is O((sqrt N)^2) = O(N) and option B is O(N) adding the constraints of C = N and A = B = sqrt(N).

Comment: Thank you for the stepwise explanation on how we got to a O(sqrt(N) * sqrt(N)) == O(N) algorithm.